# Rate limit function 40/second with "golang.org/x/time/rate"

Tags: go

I'm trying to use "golang.org/x/time/rate" to build a function which blocks until a token is free. Is this the correct way to use the library to rate limit blocks of code to 40 requests per second, with a bucket size of 2.

```
type Client struct {
    limiter        *rate.Limiter
    ctx context.Context
}

func NewClient() *Client {
    c :=Client{}
    c.limiter = rate.NewLimiter(40, 2)
    c.ctx = context.Background()
    return &c
}

func (client *Client) RateLimitFunc() {

    err := client.limiter.Wait(client.ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("rate limit error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

To rate limit a block of code I call

```
RateLimitFunc()
```

I don't want to use a ticker as I want the rate limiter to take into account the length of time the calling code runs for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading the documentation here; [link](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate#NewLimiter)

You can see that the first parameter to `NewLimiter` is of type `rate.Limit`.

If you want 40 requests / second then that translates into a rate of 1 request every 25 ms.

You can create that by doing:

```golang
limiter := rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(25 * time.Millisecond), 2)
```

Side note:

- In generate, a context, `ctx`, should not be stored on a struct and should be per request. It would appear that `Client` will be reused, thus you could pass a context to the `RateLimitFunc()` or wherever appropriate instead of storing a single context on the client struct.

Comment: Just want to point out that it might be more intuitive and readable to write this as `rate.Every(time.Second / 40)` instead of converting 40 req/sec to ms/req first.

Comment: The docs already define [Limit](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/time/rate#Limit)  _as number of events per second_ - so why not simply `rate.Limit(40)`?

Comment: Opinion based:

I would suggest that `rate.Limit(40)` may be possible, but without reading the docs it's also possible to mis-understand this as the limiter is limited to 40 requests total.

Comment: _MY_ comment was opinion based.. not the docs or the response.

Comment: Re *"In generate"*: Do you mean *"In general"*?

Answer (score 0):

```
func RateLimit(ctx context.Context) {
    limiter := rate.NewLimiter(40, 10)
    err := limiter.Wait(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // Log the error and return
    }
    // Do the actual work here
}
```

As [Zak said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900121/rate-limit-function-40-second-with-golang-org-x-time-rate/54900613#54900613), do not store Context inside a struct type according to the Go documentation [context](https://pkg.go.dev/context@go1.17).